# _32_ and _64_ equivalents in Visual C++

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

I would like to define the *32* (32 bit compilation) and *64* (64 bit compilation) in Visual C. Is there any predefined macros for this? I've scoured through MSDN in vain.

Do you think this kind of definition for *32* and *64* would work?

```
#define _32_ if !(defined __LP64__ || defined __LLP64__) || defined _WIN32 && !defined _WIN64
        // we are compiling for a 32-bit system
the else statement will be _64_ definition
        // we are compiling for a 64-bit system
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx):

> **_M_IX86**: Defined for x86 processors. ... This is not defined for x64 processors.
>
> **_M_X64**: Defined for x64 processors.
>
> **_M_IA64**: Defined for Itanium Processor Family 64-bit processors.
>
> **_WIN32**: Defined for applications for Win32 and Win64. Always defined.
>
> **_WIN64**: Defined for applications for Win64.

Take your pick.

Comment: @sblom : Good question -- VC++ 2012 obviously supports ARM (it must for ARM Win8 tablets), but I don't see any macro for it.

Answer (score 1):

You could get bogged down trying to enumerate all possible processor architectures and understanding their int-size, but I'd recommend using [`_WIN64`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx), which is defined when you're building a 64-bit executable on any processor and isn't defined when you're building for 32 bits.

Visual C++ has supported it quite far back--maybe even Visual C++ 2003.

Answer (score 1):

There is always the _WIN64 preprocessor macro.  Raymond Chen covers the subject well: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/09/06/742710.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you check [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay%28VS.80%29.aspx) it says `_M_X64` is defined for 64-bit processors.